# Rendering HTML Tags Laravel 5 Blade Templating

Tags: html, laravel, view, rendering, laravel-blade

I'm working on a Laravel App and I am displaying a content from the database, the datatype is `text` and this is the content

`<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">What is your dog's name?</span>`

As you can see it has HTML tags but when I rendered it in my view, instead of formatting the text `What is your dog's name?` It is displaying the entire content

```
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">What is your dog's name?</span>
```

It's not reading the HTML tag. Is there a convertion that I need to do in the formatting? When I view source it,

```
&lt;span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"&gt;What is your dog's name?&lt;/span&gt;
```

Here's my code:

View

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">                                
    <tbody>
       @foreach($questions as $key => $value)
           <tr>
               <td class="">{{ $value->Question }}</td>
           </tr>
       @endforeach
   </tbody>
```

My controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $questions = Question::where('IsEnabled', '=', 'Yes')->get();

    return view('crm.create')->with(array('questions' => $questions));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell blade not to escape HTML by using this `{!! !!}`

NB: This is applicable if you are using Laravel 5

```
@foreach($questions as $key => $value)
  <tr>
     <td class="">{!! $value->Question !!}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Wow. Never thought of it. Thank you so much. Works perfect! Will select this as answer after the timer. Thanks!